# Проблема с многопоточностью сервера

Tags: c#

Сделал многопоточный сервер, подключаясь он создает под пользователя отдельный поток. Все бы ничего, но клиент вначале запрашивает Crossdomain, затем отключает пользователя и снова подключается к серверу уже без запроса Crossdomain.

```
string client_type = "new";
        string data = null;
        byte[] bytes;
        int bytesRec;

        // Начинаем слушать соединения
        while (true)
        {

            // Программа приостанавливается, ожидая входящее соединение
            Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
            if (client_type == "new")
            {
                bytes = new byte[1024];
                bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                Console.WriteLine("Полученные данные: {0}", data);

                if (data == "<policy-file-request/>\0")
                {
                    string cross = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"7777\" /></cross-domain-policy>\0";
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cross);
                    handler.Send(msg);
                    client_type = "client";
                    Console.WriteLine("Отправка CrossDomain");
                }

            } else {
            ClientObject clientObject = new ClientObject(handler);

            // создаем новый поток для обслуживания нового клиента
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new 
            ThreadStart(clientObject.Process));
            clientThread.Start();
          }
        }
```

Я попробовал сделать так, но это продолжает работает только для одного пользователя. Чтобы снова зайти на сервер необходимо его перезапустить.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вызвать перед Accept, методы  либо Bind(EndPoint), либо Listen(Int32). Так по сути сам Accept не запускает прослушивание, а только ставит в режим приёма.

Comment: У меня перед while как раз все это есть. Дело в том, что при подключении и отправки Crossdomain, значение new заменяется на client, при подключении второго клиента, значение будет равно уже client. Нужно как-то сделать, чтобы при подключении нового пользователя (которому еще не отправлен Crossdomain) значение переменной было new, а если crossdomain отправлен, то client

Comment: @Александр Ну тогда вам нужно вести учёт пользователей(либо ответов), либо в по заголовку запроса(не просто проверять его по тегу, а именно знать отправляли вы ему что-то или нет).

Comment: И еще такой вопрос, почему вам не подошёл httpListner для прослушивания?